# Using JQuery, how can I prevent users from entering script or html into input fields?

Tags: jquery, input

Basically, I need to be able to strip script and html from input fields before processing.  I am using JQuery, and was hoping to find that there is a standard way of doing that sort of thing.  Any ideas?

Comment: Don't.  You should escape your content on the server.

Comment: I had thought about that, and it is easy enough to do, but was under the impression that it would be wise to prevent potentially harmful scripts from being submitted.

Comment: No, it's wise to ensure the server can handle potentially-malicious scripts instead. And you can't really do a belt-and-braces approach (e.g., doing it on *both* the client and server), because you end up either trying to detect whether something's encoded properly (vulnerability) or double-encoding it (which is a pain).

Comment: Thank you SLaks, probably saved me hours here.  How do I accept your answer, it is not showing under the Answers heading?

Comment: I added that as an answer; you can now accept it.  You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

your html:

```
<input class="striphtml" name="name" />
```

your js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // strip all html when text in input changes
  $(".striphtml").change(function(){
      $(this).val( $(this).text() );
  });
});
```

**Result:**

```
<p>This is a test.</p>
```

will be replaced with:

```
&lt;p&gt;This is a test.&lt;/p&gt;
```

**Attention:** As SLaks mentioned you MUST validate your INPUTS on server side!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it on the server. If you do it on the client, you leave yourself open to people hand-crafting HTTP messages to send to your server, knowing that your server assumes your client code escapes the strings. So, since your server can't assume the content is safe, it *has* to assume that it *isn't* safe. (Otherwise you end up double-encoding things, and that becomes a pain.) So it's neither possible, nor appropriate, for your client-side code to do the escaping.

Comment: Fair point, and well put.  I had thought that it would be sensible to do both client AND server side, but I see what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great tutorial for what you need.  As SLaks said, do this server side.  Sanitize your input

[Tutorial](http://www.denhamcoote.com/php-howto-sanitize-database-inputs)

You could do some regular expression work with specific characters, but that can only help a little bit.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, but I don't use PHP.  However, I understand the point and will take SLaks advice.

Comment: Sorry, I Just assumed Html, CSS, Jquery, and PHP!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing this at all.

Instead, you should escape your content on the server.
This way, you can accept malicious input (or `<` characters) without being harmed by it.